# WPF Databinding a Custom Control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

So I've spent about two hours pounding my head against the desk trying everything I can think of to bind to a property on a custom control and none of it works. If I have something like this:

```
<Grid Name="Form1">
    <mine:SomeControl MyProp="{Binding ElementName=Form1, Path=DataContext.Enable}"/>
    <Button Click="toggleEnabled_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public class TestPage : Page
{
    private TestForm _form;

    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form = new TestForm();
        Form1.DataContext = _form;
    }

    public void toggleEnabled_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _form.Enable = !_form.Enable;
    }
}
```

TestForm looks like:

```
public class TestForm
{
    private bool _enable;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool Enable
    {
       get { return _enable; }
       set { _enable = value; OnPropertyChanged("Enable"); }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And my control looks like:

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBox Name="TestBox"/>
</UserControl>
```

```
public class SomeControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProp", typeof(bool), typeof(SomeControl));

    public bool MyProp
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(MyPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropProperty, value); }
    }

    public SomeControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(MyPropProperty)
            .AddValueChanged(this, Enable);
    }

    public void Enable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestBox.IsEnabled = (bool)GetValue(MyPropProperty);
    }
}
```

Absolutely nothing happens when I click the toggle button. If I put a breakpoint inside of the `Enable` callback it is never hit, whats the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Enabled` method does not do any more than setting the propertou you could drop it and bind the `TextBox.IsEnabled` directly:

```
<UserControl Name="control">
    <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding MyProp, ElementName=control}"/>
</UserControl>
```

If you want to keep such a method you should register a property changed callback via [`UIPropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uipropertymetadata.aspx) for the dependency property.

---

Also this binding is redundant:

```
{Binding ElementName=Form1, Path=DataContext.Enable}
```

The `DataContext` is inherited (if you don't set it in the `UserControl` (which you should never do!)), so you can just use:

```
{Binding Enable}
```

Further if there is trouble with any of the bindings: [There are ways to debug them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Comment: I was under the impression `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(MyPropProperty)            .AddValueChanged(this, Enable);` would cause `Enable` to be called on any change of that dependency property? Also, this is a gross simplification of what I am actually doing. It just adequately represents the issue.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: Oh, i scanned your code for any calls but missed that you passed it as reference there. Don't use the descriptor for that, add a property changed callback when you register the DP. (Use the respective [metadata constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uipropertymetadata.aspx)).

Comment: That is static though? How can it reference controls on the current instance?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: The current instance is passed to the property changed callback as first argument. You can search SO for it if you need usage examples or see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx).

Comment: If you update your answer to reflect the comments I can accept it

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: Added a paragraph about the callback.